# Unable to send mail with yii

Tags: php, email, yii, swiftmailer

I am currently working on a project. Every thing is working fine on my localhost. But when I am putting it online, then After registration, it raise an error in  mail sending. The error is as :

```
include(Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_QpContentEncoder.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This project is in yii, and have put all of the configuration. The site is live at

http://eexamhall.com/apps/index.php/users/index

The problem is at mail sending on registration. How can I solve this ?

Comment: in which path u added swiftMailer folder?

Comment: in extension folder, yii-mail

Comment: swiftMalier folder direct add in extension then try.i hope it help u

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,
swiftMailer should be in "protected/vendors" folder (good practise).

Then in YiiMail.php change path in:

```
public function registerScripts() {
    if (self::$registeredScripts) {
        return;
    }

    self::$registeredScripts = true;
    require(Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/swiftMailer/classes/Swift.php');
    Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Swift', 'autoload'));
    require(Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/swiftMailer/swift_init.php');
}
```

And everything should be good.

BTW, I use https://code.google.com/p/yii-mail/ with new http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: That was not the problem of path, actually when I uploaded the system then there was some problem in uploader so some files could not be uploaded, but +1 for suggesting the good pratise ...